# How can i check validationmessagefor in mvc has a value (if model is not valid) from the client side

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How can i check  @[Html.ValidationMessageFor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.validationextensions.validationmessagefor(v=vs.118).aspx)() in mvc has a value (if model is not valid) from the client side.

I want to check it from the client side.

Comment: The `<span>` element created by `@Html.ValidationMessageFor()` will contain the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially the `@Html.ValidationMessageFor` doesn't render any value and it just represents a blank span tag with `field-validation-valid` class attribute.

Once you submit the form and client side validation called; if the associated input field is empty or some other error then it will render the error message.

So to check that a input field has any error message you need to check its data binding attributes. For example a textbox has a validation for not empty then the render output for this field will be:

```
<input type="text" value="" name="PageName" id="PageName" 
 data-val-required="*required" data-val="true">
```

In above `data-val-required` has that error message which will be appeared in `ValidationMessageFor` span element.

In order to check this from client side you need to get its attribute value in jQuery to read it, like below:

```
console.log($('#PageName').data('val-required'));
```

**Update**

If you only need to check that your form is validate or not then you can directly use `$('form').validate().valid()`.

**Note:** In above you need to have a reference of `jquery.validate.js`.

Hope this helps !!